# Can I have my cyberglove p5 working?

Tags: drivers, input

I have recently got this cool device:

[image]

However, I can't find -any- information on it and ubuntu together, so i was wondering if any of you have any experience with this.

I don't know anything about it, I can tell you it has 5 sticks for the fingers, a strap to strap around your hand and for buttons. The glove itself is connected to the "tower" through a mouse-socket, and the tower is connected to the laptop through USB.

My brother thinks "I" might need to create my own driver for it in order to have it working, but im a noob on a higher level, so I don't know how to do that at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little searching with Google found this site about how you might be able to do it: [P5 Glove & Pure-Data in Linux](http://www.noisybox.net/computers/p5glove/).

Comment: ah, i dind't think of searching for p5, i only searched for "cyberglove ubuntu" hehe, thank you very much for helping me

Comment: However, neither i, nor my brother, can make the p5 glove work, we've tried to use this method, but it doesn't work out, although, this solution seems to be the only solution currently...